# Почему findViewById(); не лучшее решение для связывания

Tags: java, android

В большинстве книг авторы используют этот метод. Слышал что это далеко не самое лучшее решение есть ли альтернатива и какие могут быть последствия. Спасибо.

Comment: как альтернативу, можно использовать [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Answer (score 5):

Проблема связывания через `findViewById` в том, что разработчик сам отвечает за написание соответствующего кода и за соответствия типов при приведении. Также хочется более простого (автоматизированного) способа накладывания данных модели на представление. Вроде бы ничего сложного, но куча дополнительных строк в `onCreate` и при заполнении представления данными, в которых можно ошибиться, а также потраченное время на написание оных - причина создавать альтернативные методы.

Если говорить об официальном способе, то это **Android Data Binding Library** от *Google*. Решение свежее, но быстро набирает популярность. Данная библиотека позволяет как избежать кода с `findViewById`, так и устраняет (в большинстве случаев) код для заполнения (!!) данными из модели. И, если я не ошибаюсь, уже есть (или еще на стадии разработки) двухстороннее связывание, что позволяет как автоматически обновлять View при изменении данных, так и наоборот (при изменении данных пользователем во View, меняются данные в объектах модели).

> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Очень популярна сторонняя библиотека **ButterKnife**. Она в свою очередь используется в качестве *синтаксического сахара* (замена `findViewById` и `setOnClickListener`). Также есть некоторые механизмы для изменения свойств View при определенных условиях.

> http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Как таковых минусов данных альтернатив я не встречал. Зависит все от того, какой проект и какая глубина использования данных библиотек в нем. Например, если использовать заполнение данными автоматически с помощью первой библиотеки, то появляется частичный код модели в xml-файле Вашего View. Для кого-то это покажется странным, кто-то найдет в этом способ инкапсулировать простейшие строки типа `textView.setText(user.getName())`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем понятно как в таком слу

Comment: Стоит добавить, что Data Binding Library не просто библиотека, а реализация паттерна MVVM в android, который совсем не свежее решение и хорошо знакомо windows-разработчикам уже много лет. Самой библиотеке DBL уже тоже более двух лет. Двухстороннее связывание так же [реализовано довольно давно](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/) (больше года уже), указывается на разметке через `=` после `@`, 
 например: `android:text="@={viewModel.address}"` для атрибутов `EditText`

Comment: Спасибо попробую оба варианта. Скажите будет ли это работать на kotlin

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за дополнение. Полностью согласен. Google очень активно продавливает MVVM. С выходом следующего API будет механизм с LiveData, который тоже значительно упрощает реализацию паттерна.

Comment: @Lexis работать на котлине будет, но смысла в ButterKnife в котлине нет. Есть KotterKnife, а он по сути является одним файлом с набором шаблонных функций - расширений для классов View, Fragment, Activity. Котлин позволяет разработчику, используя возможности языка, реализовывать ленивые `findViewById` в виде генерик-расширений, что устраняет необходимость в механизме Annotation Processing, применяемом в ButterKnife для Java. А DBL одинаково применяется в обоих языках, так как смысл в ней и область ее применения более широкие (спасибо комментарию от @pavloff).

Comment: [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) (куда входит и LiveData) доступен в виде подключаемой​ библиотеки уже сейчас (текущее состояние правда alpha1) на всех актуальных API.

Comment: @pavlofff Вот из-за альфы я пока не стремлюсь рефакторить существующий код. Попробовать для своего приложения готов, но в продакшн пока боязно.

Answer (score 4):

Смотря в каком контексте это считать не лучшим решением. Этот метод используется со времён появления Андроид и ничего криминального в нём нет. Если он вас устраивает, то не нужно ничего менять.

Есть мнение, что он работает медленно из за того, что при каждом вызове проходит по всей структуре вью в поисках нужного `id`. Но вы это заметите, только на очень большом количестве вью, или если используеье этот метод не правильно. В подтверждении этому имеется [исследование Dan Lew](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html) датированное далёким 2013-м годом.

Если же считать это не лучшим решением в плане количества написанного кода для связывания вью с кодом, то тут есть решение без использования сторонних библиотек. Определите этот метод в базовом классе активити и наследуйте ваши активити от неё:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends View> T fvbi(@IdRes int resId) {
    return (T) findViewById(resId);
}
```

Использовать так:

```
TextView tvInfo = fvbi(R.id.tvInfo);
```

Код становится немного короче и нет нудного приведения классов.

Есть и другие альтернативы, в виде сторонних библиотек.

- [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) только вот
  кода с ним едва ли становится меньше, и под капотом используется тот
  же самый `fingViewById()`. Так что улучшения производительности вы
  вряд ли увидете.
- [Data Binding
  Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)
  официальная библиотека от Google. Довольно удобная и большая, и
  замена `fingViewById()` лишь малая часть её функционала.
- Бонус. Если вы пишете на Kotlin, то можно использовать [Kotlin
  Android
  Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

Лично я использую вариант с базовой активити и функцию `fvbi()`, что меня вполне устраивает.